# Query specific user emails

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Our goal here is to get the emails of the specific users within a specific received date time and lists only the following mail properties:

from, toRecipients, ccRecipients, bccRecipients

Here's the query that we ran

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@contoso.com/messages$select=from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2019-07-01 and receivedDate lt 2019-07-02

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@contoso.com/messages$select=from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients$filter=ReceivedDateTime ge 2019-07-01 and receivedDate lt 2019-07-02
```

Error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorFolderNotFound",
        "message": "The specified folder could not be found in the store.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "8b58633d-3e7f-4e25-a6bc-bd1562340bc4",
            "date": "2019-07-30T15:11:12"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query link has a couple mistakes in it:

1. Since `$select` and `$filter` attributes are a part of the URL query string, they must be preceded by `?`
2. `$filter` is a separate parameter from `$select`, so they must be separated by `&`
3. The selected/filtered attributes must match exactly to what the API supplies, including case (you wrote "ReceivedDateTime" and "receivedDate", both of which should be "receivedDateTime"

Here is the corrected URL:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@contoso.com/messages?$select=from,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients&$filter=receivedDateTime ge 2019-07-01 and receivedDateTime lt 2019-07-02`

For a list of all mail properties available, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)